# Open Link to Instagram Native

Tags: objective-c, facebook, instagram

To open a Facebook Native profile, I can use:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/<id>"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

Is there any way to do the same thing for an Instagram profile?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Following Snippet will open instagram app on your device with userName.

**Objective C**

```
NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=USERNAME"];
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];
}
```

**Swift**

```
var instagramURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME")
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramURL)
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
let instagramURL:URL = URL(string: "instagram://user?username=USERNAME")!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramURL) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(instagramURL, options:[:], completionHandler: { (Bool) in
        print("Completion block")
    })
}
```

if you want more details about it you can refere following [Documentation link](http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/#)

Comment: How can we get Profile information like username and user email id..can any one resolve this issue

Comment: kindly go through this link you will get your answer in Documentaion of Instagram http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#

Comment: Do you have any sample can u please send me am very new to IOS

Comment: I have already written sample for it. for more code you can refer document.

Comment: Broken link (Documentation link)

Comment: Documentation is updated, this is [latest link](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/). @EvgenyFedin Happy coding :)