# How do I make a link open an Instagram page in an app installed on android?

Tags: android, hyperlink

I need to know how to make a link open an Instagram page in an app if the app is installed on a smartphone.

A simple way such as `www.instagram.com/example` links you to page by browser, which is not what I want.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 12):

**Try this :**

Works 100% `<a href="instagram://user?username=untitled.tiff">untitled.tiff</a>`

Comment: This works! It ask "Open in app?", then opens it in the native Instagram app.

Comment: this worked for me. May I ask how did you know about this url?

Comment: Only works if the Instagram app is installed.

Answer (score 9):

Launching instagram from the browser.
To launch instagram form a link it should be enough to provide a link as:

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/p/<picture id>">look at this instagram picture</a>
```

example: [look at this instagram picture](http://instagram.com/p/0nUyKnMJw4)

```
<a href="http://instagram.com/p/0nUyKnMJw4">look at this instagram picture</a>
```

Try opening that link on an android device. Also, keep in mind instagram must be installed on the device. 
For users replace the "p" with "_u" and the picture id with the username.

Why will this work? The instagram application has an intent listener for http and https browses

```
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/p/" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/p/" android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_u/" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_u/" android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_uid/" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_uid/" android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_n/" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="instagram.com" android:pathPrefix="/_n/" android:scheme="https"/>
```

Edit: It apears I had an old Manifest file.

Comment: unfortunately its completely Unclear for me! what should i do whit this??!

Comment: should i copy and past it somewhere??

Comment: Ah, you wish to launch an activity from within your webbrowser.

Comment: Instead of `www.instagram.com/example` use `www.instagram.com/_u/example`.

And your intent will look like this
`startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.instagram.com/_u/example/")));`

Comment: @AbhinavUpadhyay This is exactly what is in my answer. Did you mean to comment this on his question? Also note he is trying to open the application from a web browser/web page not from another app.

Comment: @RobbeRoels, my bad, I did mean to comment on the question. Also, I like your way of answering. That certainly covers all the aspects.

Comment: @abhinavUpadhyay thank you, I was confused and thought I missed something

Answer (score 5):

It worked for me.

```
try {
    // mediaLink is something like "https://instagram.com/p/6GgFE9JKzm/" or 
    // "https://instagram.com/_u/sembozdemir"
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(mediaLink);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    intent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: How you will do the same for iOS?

Comment: You should search for it. I found this for you when I googled it. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16370613/4557274

Comment: This is only for username. But i found it. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: How to do it in PHP ?

Answer (score 2):

You can open by android intent on browser anchor link. You can get detailed information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents)

```
<a href="intent://instagram.com/#Intent;package=com.instagram.android;scheme=https;end">Open Instagram</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use Intent, you can use Intent to send data, a intent(short of intention) is used to "broadcast" a message, and apps that are listening to it will respond.

See it as an email i send to a bunch of my friends were i ask mark to do something, mark will respond but the rest will ignore the email.

You can send an intent by using this code(this one is specific to your question but can easily be edited to fit other needs):

```
Intent insta_intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.instagram.android");
insta_intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.instagram.android", "com.instagram.android.activity.UrlHandlerActivity"));

//use this if you want to open an image
insta_intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/p/gjfLqSBQTJ/"));

//And if you want to open a user's profile use this
insta_intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://instagram.com/_u/USER"));

startActivity(insta_intent);
```

Comment: maartin? im not programmer expert, please directly give me a link to open instagram.com/foodiq  which link me to this page but by app, not by browser.

Comment: Ah, you just want a link to click on/put on a website that will open the app?

Comment: This link works for me(note, it won't work when typed in the search bar in google chrome): " http://instagram.com/_u/foodiq " screenshot: [link](http://prntscr.com/6l3wqo)

Comment: some phones ask how to open the link,(by app, chrome, or ...) like your screenshot you sent, but some phones like me don't, this way dose not grantee to open by app. this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method. You can have the POPUP to choice open link via Instagram or Browser.
(This method uses for any link you want, Not just Instagram.)

```
***.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
String url = "Your URL";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```